# Calculating average slope of line using QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I am new to GIS and QGIS.  I am using QGIS3.2 on Apple Silicon/OSX.  I am trying to calculate the approximate average slope in percentage of a ski run (piste), which is a line, using a calculated field.  I have a DEM/30m/wgs84.  There are many data I cannot understand how to obtain and therefore cannot calculate the average slope.

General overview of how to calculate;

- Slope is 'elevation change' over 'horizontal distance' / 100.
- Most skis runs (pistes) are on average about 500m to 2 or 3 km).
- I think the best idea is to divide the line into, say, 10 segments and calculate 10 slopes in percent.  Then, I am to finally add the 10 slopes together and divide by 10.

How can I get this data?  Here is where I struggle:

- To get the length of the line, I think `$length`  is ok here.
- To get the the elevation of the start of the line, I use:

  `raster_value('MyDEM', 1, make_point($x_at(0),$y_at(0)))`
- How can I jump 1/10th of the way down the line and get the elevation there?
- How can I get the 'jumped' distance in meters returned?
- I assume to get the elevation of the end of the line , I use;

  `raster_value('MyDEM', 1, make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1)))`

I tried to use a plugin called Road Slope Calculator ([RSC](https://github.com/Almeida100/RSC)) here, however, it crashes on my Apple Silicon.

Would this be better handled with Python?  I would prefer to make it a calculated field.

Comment: Surely the "average" slope is simply the difference in elevation between the start and the end, divided by the line length.

Comment: This seems overly complex. You already have all of the key pieces above - start elevation, end elevation and length. Dividing the line into 10 segments is creating complexity where none is needed. As @LeighBettenay says, just do the slope calculation. (elevationAtStart-elevationAtEnd) / $length (and multiply by 100 if you want a %)